# How to set the last inner div to fill the rest of the wrapper height with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html, height

I would like to create a wrapper div that contains 2 inner divs so that the wrapper and the first inner divs will have a fixed height and the second inner div will fill the rest of the wrapper height.
I have done something like this:

```
<div class="frameArea">
   <div class="header"></div>
   <div class="frame"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS file looks like this:

```
.frameArea {
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 2px solid black;
}
.frameArea .header {
   background-color: green;
   width: 100%;
   height: 25px;
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 25px;
}
.frameArea .frame {
   background-color: white;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

The thing is, that using this CSS making the .frame div to be 100% of the **wrapper's height**, which means he will be 300px instead of what i'm looking for - 275px (in this case when the wrapper is 300px and the .header is 25px).
One way I can do this by setting the height property of .frame using JS code that will calculate and set it dynamically when the document is ready, however I would like to ask if there is any CSS property that does the same in more elegant way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS `calc()`

```
.frameArea .frame {
    ...
    height: calc(100% - 25px);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/jeCrk/)

`calc()` is not compatible with older browsers and thus might give you compatibility problems, to overcome this I suggest you use `JavaScript` solution.

**A `jQuery` Solution**

```
var h = $('div.frameArea').height() - 25;
$('div.frame').height(h);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/jeCrk/1/)

Comment: Thanks. As you said, It may cause compatibility issues (It worked for me on Chrome but not in IE), however I'll keep in mind your solution and use my JS solution (which is similar to yours) as a fallback. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jsFiddle with the solution. The answer is a simple CSS solution. Just change the `.frame` `height: 100%;` to `height: auto;`.

EDIT: Sorry, wrong fiddle. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/UX6XQ/1/embedded/result/

Comment: Its wrong. You can detect it bu changing `background-color` to any color other than white or use dev tools (chrome) / firebug (ff). `height: auto`doesn't give it remaining height